# Choice Menu not selecting correct errorlevels

Tags: windows, batch-file, errorlevel, multiple-choice

I'm having a problem with a choice menu executing the proper errorlevel. My batch file goes to the first item (A), and executes that no matter which choice I select by keyboard in the menu. In the sample below, if I select 'C', then `(IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="c" GOTO :c495)` should execute. My problem is that `(IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="a" GOTO :a299)` is executing no matter what key I press. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my batch file?

```
@echo off
    cls
        echo.
        echo          A   $2.99                 H   $4.99
        echo          B   $3.99                 I   $9.99
        echo          C   $4.95                 J  $14.95
        echo          D   $5.99                 K  $19.95
        echo          E   $6.99                 L  $29.95
        echo          F   $8.99                 M  $39.95
        echo          G   $9.95                 N  $49.95
        echo          ___________________________________
        echo.
        echo                   Press 'Q' to Quit


        echo.
        CHOICE /N /C:abcdefghijklmnq /M "  SELECT A LETTER "%1
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="q" GOTO :xEOF
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="n" GOTO :n4995
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="m" GOTO :m3995
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="l" GOTO :l2995
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="k" GOTO :k1995
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="j" GOTO :j1495
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="i" GOTO :i999
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="h" GOTO :h499
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="g" GOTO :g995
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="f" GOTO :f899
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="e" GOTO :e699
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="d" GOTO :d599
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="c" GOTO :c495
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="b" GOTO :b399
    IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="a" GOTO :a299



 :a299
IF NOT EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" GOTO :NullFile
IF EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" COPY "c:\Users\admin\Documents\ProgramData\Bin\Prices\3D Cover - 299.png" "blank12.png"
GOTO :Compile


 :b399
IF NOT EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" GOTO :NullFile
IF EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" COPY "c:\Users\admin\Documents\ProgramData\Bin\Prices\3D Cover - 399.png" "blank12.png"
GOTO :Compile

 :c495
IF NOT EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" GOTO :NullFile
IF EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" COPY "c:\Users\admin\Documents\ProgramData\Bin\Prices\3D Cover - 495.png" "blank12.png"
GOTO :Compile

 :d599
IF NOT EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" GOTO :NullFile
IF EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" COPY "c:\Users\admin\Documents\ProgramData\Bin\Prices\3D Cover - 599.png" "blank12.png"
GOTO :Compile
```

The code goes on from here, but works fine from this point on.
Thank you.

Comment: `choice` sets a number to the `errorlevel` but not a letter. Try to change comparisons to numbers.

Comment: Please open up a Command Prompt window, enter **`choice /?`**, read the usage information, then try to implement the information you've read within that output!

Comment: in your case `a` will produce `1` , `b` - 2 and so on. Here's an example: https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html

Comment: Does that mean the number of choices is limited to 9 only?

Comment: It looks like you have an extra space in your comparisons. You have `IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" =="c" GOTO` instead of `IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="c" GOTO`. There for it will not match any of the statements and because you have nothing after the comparisons to stop it from continuing without a valid response it then continues on and does the first action....which is equivalent to entering `a`. To check, put a `pause` after the last `IF %ERRORLEVEL%` line then run and enter `c`. If it displays the pause.... then it did not run the `GOTO` command and I stead found no match and continued on with the script...

Comment: Removed the spaces, and it seems to make no difference. Changed the errorlevels as follows and it works for levels 1 to 9 but not for J to Q even though I do not get an error code beep when depression the J to Q keys which occurs when a wrong key is pressed.

     CHOICE /N /C:123456789jklmnq /M "  SELECT A LETTER "%1
     IF %ERRORLEVEL%==q GOTO :xEOF
 IF %ERRORLEVEL%==n GOTO :n4995
 IF %ERRORLEVEL%==m GOTO :m3995
 IF %ERRORLEVEL%==l GOTO :l2995
 IF %ERRORLEVEL%==k GOTO :k1995
 IF %ERRORLEVEL%==j GOTO :j1495

Comment: You'll need to use multiple levels of menu, or use an alternative input method if you want more than nine possible choices.

Comment: I wonder if its possible to use some variation of: 

choice /n/c:;0123456789'''''''ABCDEF > nul
    for %%v in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F) do if errorlevel }%%v set X
=%%v
    choice /n/c;0123456789'''''''ABCDEF %X%
    for %%v in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F) do if errorlevel }%%v set X
=%X%%%v
    ECHO.
    ECHO. (Your input) = (%X%)

Comment: Compo, what do you mean by "alternative input method"? Thanks

Comment: @Phaedrus, don't use `choice.exe`.

Comment: Change to `set /p choice=Select a letter: ` then use `IF "%choice%"=="a" GOTO`....

Comment: Durry42 - Ahhh, Yes, that works too. It's the best way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
    cls
        echo/
        echo          A   $2.99                 H   $4.99
        echo          B   $3.99                 I   $9.99
        echo          C   $4.95                 J  $14.95
        echo          D   $5.99                 K  $19.95
        echo          E   $6.99                 L  $29.95
        echo          F   $8.99                 M  $39.95
        echo          G   $9.95                 N  $49.95
        echo          ___________________________________
        echo/
        echo                   Press 'Q' to Quit


        echo/
        CHOICE /N /C:abcdefghijklmnq /M "  SELECT A LETTER "

    goto option-%errorlevel%


 :option-1  a299
ECHO a299
GOTO :EOF

IF NOT EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" GOTO :NullFile
IF EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" COPY "c:\Users\admin\Documents\ProgramData\Bin\Prices\3D Cover - 299.png" "blank12.png"
GOTO :Compile


 :option-2  b399
ECHO b399
GOTO :EOF

IF NOT EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" GOTO :NullFile
IF EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" COPY "c:\Users\admin\Documents\ProgramData\Bin\Prices\3D Cover - 399.png" "blank12.png"
GOTO :Compile

 :option-3  c495
ECHO c495
GOTO :EOF

IF NOT EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" GOTO :NullFile
IF EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" COPY "c:\Users\admin\Documents\ProgramData\Bin\Prices\3D Cover - 495.png" "blank12.png"
GOTO :Compile

 :option-14  n4995
ECHO n4995
GOTO :EOF

IF NOT EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" GOTO :NullFile
IF EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" COPY "c:\Users\admin\Documents\ProgramData\Bin\Prices\3D Cover - 599.png" "blank12.png"
GOTO :Compile

 :option-15  q
ECHO QUIT
```

PS - I don't understand the comments about a "maximum of 9 options in **choice** command". Choice allows as possible options all digits and letters (upcase and lowcase may be different) and some special characters, so it may have more than 62 different options...

... and a *much* simpler method:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "list=299,399,495,599,699,899,995,499,999,1495,1995,2995,3995,4995" 

    cls
        echo/
        echo          A   $2.99                 H   $4.99
        echo          B   $3.99                 I   $9.99
        echo          C   $4.95                 J  $14.95
        echo          D   $5.99                 K  $19.95
        echo          E   $6.99                 L  $29.95
        echo          F   $8.99                 M  $39.95
        echo          G   $9.95                 N  $49.95
        echo          ___________________________________
        echo/
        echo                   Press 'Q' to Quit


        echo.
        CHOICE /N /C:abcdefghijklmnq /M "  SELECT A LETTER "

if %errorlevel% equ 15 goto :EOF

for /F "tokens=%errorlevel% delims=," %%a in ("%list%") do set "file=%%a"

echo File: "c:\Users\admin\Documents\ProgramData\Bin\Prices\3D Cover - %file%.png"
```

Comment: Wonderful. That's an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out the answer. It required a totally different way of thinking about it:

```
@echo off
    cls
        echo.
        echo          1   $2.99                 A   $4.99
        echo          2   $3.99                 B   $9.99
        echo          3   $4.95                 C  $14.95
        echo          4   $5.99                 D  $19.95
        echo          5   $6.99                 E  $29.95
        echo          6   $8.99                 F  $39.95
        echo          7   $9.95                 G  $49.95
        echo          ___________________________________
        echo.
        echo                   Press 'Q' to Quit




@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "list=299,399,495,599,699,899,995,499,999,1495,1995,2995,3995,4995,q" 
set "allchoices=1234567abcdefghijklmnopqABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ"
set count=0
for %%A in (%list%) do (
  rem call echo %%allchoices:~!count!,1%%: %%A
  set /a count+=1
  set "list[!count!]=%%A"
)
set "choices=!allchoices:~0,%count%!"
choice /cs /N /C:1234567abcdefgqABCDEFGQ /M "SELECT A LETTER: "
GoTo !list[%errorlevel%]!




 :299
ENDLOCAL
IF NOT EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" GOTO :NullFile
IF EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" COPY "c:\Users\admin\Documents\ProgramData\Bin\Prices\3D Cover - 299.png" "blank12.png"
GOTO :Compile



 :399
ENDLOCAL
IF NOT EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" GOTO :NullFile
IF EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" COPY "c:\Users\admin\Documents\ProgramData\Bin\Prices\3D Cover - 399.png" "blank12.png"
GOTO :Compile


 :495
ENDLOCAL
IF NOT EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" GOTO :NullFile
IF EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" COPY "c:\Users\admin\Documents\ProgramData\Bin\Prices\3D Cover - 495.png" "blank12.png"
GOTO :Compile


 :599
ENDLOCAL
IF NOT EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" GOTO :NullFile
IF EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" COPY "c:\Users\admin\Documents\ProgramData\Bin\Prices\3D Cover - 599.png" "blank12.png"
GOTO :Compile


 :699
ENDLOCAL
IF NOT EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" GOTO :NullFile
IF EXIST "*Cover (300 DPI).jpg" COPY "c:\Users\admin\Documents\ProgramData\Bin\Prices\3D Cover - 699.png" "blank12.png"
GOTO :Compile
```

Thanks to everyone for their assistence.